# M1 Pro Python XGBoost not using all cores

Tags: python, xgboost, apple-m1

I am currently using the M1 Pro MacBook Pro with 10 cores. When using XGBoost in Python, only 6 of the cores at most are used. I have had this working fine in the M1 MacBook Air and it was running with all 8 cores.

Has anybody had any issues with this? I have tried changing the n_jobs using -1 and 10 and all show the same CPU usage.

XGBoost is installed through Conda-forge and Miniforge used for python on arm apple silicone.

Comment: Number of cores doesn't matter while the machine is bandwidth limited.